# Why is this mongoose code receiving a cast error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Did I make a mistake in defining the model or is there an error in the way that the server code was written?

The error that I am getting is:
Error: CastError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[\n  { contact: new ObjectId(ID_OF_CONTACT_STRING), title: 'test' }\n]" (type string) at path "relations.0" because of "CastError"

The mongoose model with the relations field looks like this:

```
const ContactSchema = new Schema(
  {
    ...
    relations: [{
      contact: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Contact'
      },
      title: String
    }],
    ...
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
)
```

Then I have the following server code:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  await connectDB();

  if (!(req.body.relationId && req.body.contactId && req.body.relationTitle)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: true, message: "Bad params", code: 1 });
  }

  if (!req.cookies.agent) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: true, message: "Not logged in", code: 202 });
  }

  try {
    const contact = await Contact.findById(req.body.contactId);
    const relation = await Contact.findById(req.body.relationId);

    if (!contact || !relation) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: true, message: "Invalid contact or relation", code: CONTACT_NOT_FOUND_CODE });
    }

    console.log(contact._id, "contact id")
    console.log(relation._id, "object id")

    const newRelation = { contact: relation._id, title: req.body.relationTitle };

    console.log(newRelation, "new relation")
    
    //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    await Contact.updateOne({_id: req.body.contactId}, {$push: {relations: newRelation}})


    return res.status(200).json({ error: false });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: "Internal server error" });
  }
}
```

In the server code, all the body parameters are strings.

Comment: Do you still get the error when you do `const newRelation = { contact: req.body.relationId, title: req.body.relationTitle };` instead?

Comment: @jQueeny yes, the error still happens. The error just becomes:

Error: CastError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[ { contact: 'CONTACT_ID', title: 'test' } ]" (type string) at path "relations.0" because of "CastError"

Comment: In my experience then the `CONTACT_ID` is not a value that can be cast to an `ObjectId`. Can you `console.log('CONTACT_ID=', req.body.contactId)` and post the output without changing it in any way. By that I mean just copy and paste directly from the terminal to your question.

Comment: @jQueeny Here is the console:
CONTACT_ID= 65f608857924211ea3722a46
RELATION_ID= 65f608857924211ea3722a46

Comment: Is there a whitespace character either just before or just after the value when you send the form/postman request to the server?

Comment: @jQueeny No white space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257206/discussion-between-pavel-halko-and-jqueeny).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I updated the schama which was used to be:

```
const ContactSchema = new Schema(
  {
    ...
    relations: [{
      contact: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Contact'
      },
      title: String
    }],
    ...
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
)
```

I was using an already made instance. I was attempting to push an object and the instance was expecting an objectId.

The solution was simply restarting the server.